# Go function declaration is really not clear what the output is

Tags: go

I have been trying to come up to speed with golang in the last few days by Watching some of the videos for gopher. I’m having a hard time figuring out the function declarations and returns. I have read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_functions.htm

And it seems straightforward however this example below confuses me.

For example in the stinger https://blog.golang.org/generate

```golang
type Pill int

const (
    Placebo Pill = iota
    Aspirin
    Ibuprofen
    Paracetamol
    Acetaminophen = Paracetamol
)

func (p Pill) String() string
```

I can see that in func the input parameter is p of type Pill but then String() and string ? What is going on the name of the function I’m assuming is string but why the output type string is after that ?

Or

```
func TestNirmalize(t *testing.T)
```

Or

```
func(th *timeHandler)ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r*http.Request{
```

Comment: See [Methods](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) in the Tour of Go and [Method Declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) in the language specification.

Comment: What do you mean by: String method on Pill with receiver named p, what is a receiver?

Comment: Please disregard my question I read about methods more and I understand what you mean by a receiver I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` is not an input parameter. That syntax where a parameter and type comes before the function signature means the type `Pill` has a [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) associated with it. The actual function signature is `String()` that takes no arguments. This declaration means that the function `String()` that takes no arguments and returns a `string` can be called on a `type Pill int`, like so:

```
Pill p
fmt.Println(p.String())
```

As for your other function signatures, note that specifying a return value or method type is optional so both examples return nothing (i.e. `void` in other langauges).

---

This accepts a pointer to type `testing.T` and returns nothing:

```
func TestNirmalize(t *testing.T)
```

---

I'm assuming there's a missing `)` in your question. This method similarly is defined on type `timeHandler`, accepts types `http.ResponseWriter` and `*http.Request` and returns nothing.

```
func(th *timeHandler)ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r*http.Request)
```